# Every time I run server my new table is being created and previous data are deleted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Whenever I run my server my database table are re-created and all my previous data are being deleted. I was thinking this might be the problem in hibernate configuration file but don't know the actual reason hope you awesome guys will figure me out .
I also tried changing `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` to auto , validate but didnot help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<!-- Assume test is the database name -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restro
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">
  root
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">
  root
</property> 
<!-- <property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property> -->
<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<!-- Names the annotated entity class  -->
<mapping class="com.restroo.model.MenuItems"/>
<mapping class="com.restroo.model.AdminUser"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Which database are u using ?

Comment: @pvpkiran I am using mySql db

Comment: try to use the MySQL5Dialect with the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate

Comment: @AmrAlaa still the same problem  after using  MySQL5Dialect with the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate

Comment: Try  `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>`  not `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`